# Create array of class object

Tags: c++, class, object

I am trying to create an array of the class object Point in the class object Polygon. When compiling I am getting several errors, can someone please help me fix these errors/suggest a better way of creating an array of class objects?

CODE DELETED

when trying to compile i get these errors:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "Point::MAX_VAL", referenced from:
          Point::Point() in ccyVCyNB.o
          Point::Point() in ccyVCyNB.o
          Point::Point(float, float)in ccyVCyNB.o
          Point::Point(float, float)in ccyVCyNB.o
          Point::set(float, float)in ccyVCyNB.o
          Point::setRange(float, float)in ccyVCyNB.o
      "Point::MIN_VAL", referenced from:
          Point::Point() in ccyVCyNB.o
          Point::Point() in ccyVCyNB.o
          Point::Point(float, float)in ccyVCyNB.o
          Point::Point(float, float)in ccyVCyNB.o
          Point::set(float, float)in ccyVCyNB.o
          Point::setRange(float, float)in ccyVCyNB.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: It would help if you could list the errors you get, preferably unedited and complete. It would help even more if you could point out the lines they are about in the provided source.

Comment: You also have other problems, that are not related to compilation but runtime. In `setPoints` you must first delete the existing pointer, and allocate a new array. Or simply use `std::vector` so you don't have to worry about memory issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
Polygon::Polygon()
{
   numPoints = 0;
   points = new Point[numPoints];
}
```

You are allocating memory for 0 objects of type `Point`. That is the problem.

Comment: It's perfectly okay to allocate zero memory like that, as long as it's not being accessed (as that would be out of bounds).

Comment: But using the default constructor followed by calling the `setPoints` member function results in accessing unallocated memory

Comment: As the size is zero, no constructor is actually called. You get a valid pointer that has to be deleted, but no constructor (or destructor in the `delete[]`) is called.

Comment: I meant the constructor of the Polygon class, i.e. a polygon object is created using the default constructor (which allocates zero memory for points), followed by a call to `setPoints` which does not allocate space for points but assigns values to its indices.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of your compilation errors are `MIN_VAL` and `MAX_VAL`, which you declare and then initialize *in the constructors*. Therefore, all references to them are undefined.

Consider using

```
class Point {
...
};

float Point::MIN_VAL = -10.0f;
float Point::MAX_VAL = 10.0f;

class Polygon {
...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really hold an `std::vector<Point>` instead of the array:

```
class Polygon
{
private:
   int numPoints;
   std::vector<Point> points;
....
};
```

Then you don't have to worry about a destructor, copy constructor, or copy assignment operator. It's default size is zero, so your default constructor becomes

```
Polygon::Polygon() : numPoints(0) {}
```

and this one:

```
Polygon::Polygon(int numPoints, float xArray[], float yArray[])
{
     for(int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
     {
       points.push_back(Point(xValues[i], yValues[i]));
     }
}
```

but in actual fact, you do not need data member `numPoints`, because you can get the number of points from the size of the vector, that is, `points.size()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But I'd like to learn how to use arrays before using vector